# Typescript dynamic object interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using javascript to create an object and want to add in an interface for the data:

Javascript:

```
const childGroups: Children = {};
      childGroups.children = [];

// Pushing some data 
childGroups.children.push(children);
```

Interface:

```
export interface Child {
    ClusterPoint
}

export interface Children {
    children: {
        [key: number]: Child
    }
}
```

I'm getting the below errors:
`Property 'children' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Children'. Property 'push' does not exist on type {[key: number]: Child}`

The data looks this:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**

Thanks to Nikita Madeev, I managed to get it to work with this:

```
export interface Child {
    children: {
        ClusterPoint
    };
}

export interface Children {
    children: Child[];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
export interface Child {
    ClusterPoint;
}

export interface Children {
    children: Child[];
}

const childGroups: Children = { children: [] };

// Pushing some data
childGroups.children.push(newChildren);
```

1. `Children.children` - object, not array, object has not push method
2. During initialization, you need to specify all the necessary properties

Comment: Thanks for this. It didn't work 100%, had to change Child interface, will add it to my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this structure

```
const childGroups: Children = {};
      childGroups.children = [];
```

then interfaces would be

```
export interface Children {
    children?: Child[];
}
```

and if you want to achieve this structure

```
const childGroups: Children = {};
      childGroups.children = {[some_id]: some_childValue};
```

then interface would be

```
export interface Children {
    children?: {
      [key: number]: Child
     };
}
```